# How to Modify Objects In a View Controller from Another one (With StoryBoards)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Ok, so, sorry if this is a noobish question but I am a noob. I want to know how with using storyboards, how can I change an object (IE the text of a label) in View 1 by say clicking a button in View 2?